# ¿Probar esta API en Postman?

Tags: nodejs, api, express, backend

Me gustaría saber como puedo interactuar con esta **API**. Me han encargado un proyecto que consiste en desarrollar una **API** para crear, consultar e interactuar con notas. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

Este sería mi controller:

```
    const _ = require("lodash");
const notes = require("../model/nodeModel");

exports.getNextId = () =>
  _.parseInt(_.maxBy(Object.keys(notes), _.parseInt)) + 1;

exports.addNote = ({ title, body, created_by }) => {
  const id = getNextId();
  notes[id] = {
    id,
    title,
    body,
    created_by,
    created_at: Date.now(),
    edit_history: [],
  };
  return notes[id];
};

exports.getNotes = () => notes;

exports.getNote = (id) => {
  const note = getNotes()[id];
  return note || null;
};

exports.favNote = (id, update) => {
  const note = getNote(id);
  _.assign(note, _.pick(update, ["title", "body"]));
  if (update.edited_by) {
    note.edit_history.push({
      edited_by: update.edited_by,
      edited_at: Date.now(),
    });
  }
  return note;
};

exports.favNotes = () => notes;
```

Aquí mi archivo de rutas:

```
const express = require("express");
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();
const _ = require("lodash");

const app = express();

const {
  getNextId,
  addNote,
  getNotes,
  getNote,
  favNotes,
  favNote,
} = require("../controllers/noteController");

app.post("/notes", (req, res) => {
  const note = addNote(req.body);
  res.json(note);
});

router.get("/notes", (req, res) => {
  res.json(_.map(getNotes()));
});

router.get("/notes/:id", (req, res) => {
  const note = getNote(req.params.id);
  res.json(note);
});

router.get("/notes/:id", (req, res) => {
  const note = favNotes(req.params.id, req.body);
  res.json(note);
});

router.put("/notes/:id", (req, res) => {
  const result = favNote(req.params.id);
  res.json(result);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Y el modelo de nota:

```
    const notes = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    title: "Test Note",
    body: "Type here whatever you want",
    created_at: Date.now(),
    created_by: "Admin",
    edit_history: [
      {
        edited_at: Date.now(),
        edited_by: "User",
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = notes;
```

Bien, este código lo he basado en otro ya creado. En ese se dice que para usar la API, por ejemplo para crear una nota, hay que hacer lo siguiente:

*CREATE
POST /notes Adds a new note, assigning it a new auto-incremented id and created_at field with the current timestamp. A new note also has an empty edit_history list. The new note is returned.

Args:

```
note:dict
    created_by:string
    title:string
    body:string
```

Returns:
note object*

Sin embargo, en Postman no sé como hacerlo... He probado como JSON, como Text, como form-data... Y ni idea. Alguna ayuda? La dirección está bien, las hago a `http://localhost:5000/notes`

Comment: Tu pregunta es varias en una. Además que es posible que se base en opiniones. *¿necesito hacer un front?* Si, no, tal vez. *¿Necesito una base de datos?* Si, no, tal vez. *¿Necesito Postman?* Seguramente si, no, tal vez. Por favor edita tu pregunta para hacerla más específica, indica cuál es el problema mostrando el código relevante que origina dicho problema y plantea cuál es el resultado esperado. Puedes leer [mcve] para que tengas una idea. Saludos

Comment: Mmmm... la cosa es que la pregunta que tengo es la que está en el post... El caso es que quiero prescindir del front, lo único que quiero es la API en sí. Lo que quiero es testear que funciona; quiero hacer algo, que cree la nota y luego algo que consulte que efectivamente esa nota esta ahí. ¿Cómo lo preguntarías?

Comment: *¿Cómo lo preguntarías?* No lo preguntaría aquí en el sitio, porque sería una pregunta basada en opiniones. Si entiendo bien, tienes ya una API desarrollada, ¿cómo la pruebas?. Si esa es la pregunta, habrá muchas opiniones al respecto, entre ellas: *usa Postman, usa Swagger, crea un Frontend, etc.* Mi consejo: elige una forma de probar tu API, por ejemplo: Postman, y comienza a realizar las peticiones necesarias, cuando una falle, revisa el código, el log de errores y si tienes dificultad con esa parte del código pues vienes al sitio y realizas la pregunta específica. Saludos

Comment: Genial. Esta información ya me es muy útil. Lo que haré será preguntar a quien me ha encargado el proyecto, porque pide la API pero no pide nada más. De ahí mi lío, no se a qué se refería exactamente. Pero ya veo que la API en sí se puede probar con Postman. Muchas gracias, sois una comunidad muy amable. Ojalá y algún día pueda ayudarte yo a tí. Un saludo!